# Add a Like + Sort Function to existing dynamic funcion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote a function that dynamically creates a webpage for me based on a json database.

Now I want to add 2 functions:

1. If you click the like img (its got the id button) the like counter should increase on the webpage by 1. Pretty easy just a on(click) with jQuery variable++ and then `.text(variable)`
2. A sort function - based on the likes one item received, you should be able to sort it (most liked div first, 2nd, 3rd....

I can write it for each individually with individual variables when I give all the like buttons and outputs a separate id but I wanted to make it dynamic so if you add new data to json file it dynamically works with the like and sort function.

The likes are not saved anywhere for now.

Since sitting on it for 3h and google so much and so much stackoverflow I think I overloaded my brain with different stuff and now nothing seems to work ^^

```
function filmInsert(insert) {
    $.each(film, function(i, data) { //.each statt loop
      let box = 

      `<div class="boxwrapper">
      <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="${data.img}" alt="${data.titel}">
    </div>
    <div class="textbox">
        <h3>${data.titel}</h3>
        <p>${data.beschreibung}</p>
        <p> <a id="button${data.id}">
          <img src="img/budspencer_official.png"> Like
          </a>
          <span class="output${data.id}">${data.likes}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>`;
      insert.append(box);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a container element for the `boxwrapper` items as I assume you have one and as it's better to have one instead of just adding the sorted items to the body of the HTML document.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".textbox a", function() {
  let likes = parseInt($(this).closest(".textbox").find("span").text());
  $(this).closest(".textbox").find("span").text(likes + 1);
});
$("#sort").on("click", function() {
  let divs = $(".boxwrapper")
  let sorted = divs.sort(function(a, b) {
     return $(a).find("span").text() < $(b).find("span").text() ? 1 : -1;
  });
  $(".container").html(sorted);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxwrapper">
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="example.gif" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="textbox">
      <h3>Titel</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
      <p> <a id="button1">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff&text=1"> Like
        </a>
        <span class="output1">0</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxwrapper">
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="example.gif" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="textbox">
      <h3>Titel 2</h3>
      <p>Description 2</p>
      <p> <a id="button2">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff&text=2"> Like
        </a>
        <span class="output2">0</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="sort">
  Sort
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the sort isnt working Oo . i just copy pastaed your code to try out ,but no sort (live server vsc)

Comment: @TomersonJefferson That's strange as it's working in the example. Is your sort button added dynamically? Can you add a console message to the sort function to see if it is called?

Comment: i tried now edge aswell ( i use chrome ) if i run the code snippet its counting likes. but when i give no2 more likes then no1 for example and click sort, nothing chagnes. also tried to run it in vsc with liveserver, no sorting :(

Comment: @TomersonJefferson I have to ask it again: Is your sort button added through code or is it initially in the page? And can you add a console message to the sort function to check if it is called?

Comment: sorry. the sort button is already on the page (like on the html code you provided thankfully to me). i did add a alert message hello to the end of the code and yes its getting called correctly but the div order remains the same - thanks for your answering matthias

Comment: @TomersonJefferson Thanks for clarification. Can you make a Fiddle with your generated HTML so it's possible to check the issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vuse6cjo/1/ ( i copied the JSON file just in the js thing)   i also uploaded the files with the img to random website so you can see what i mean maybe: https://easyupload.io/gkfsmw  -  didnt implemented your geourges template yet because it isnt working on its own atm

Comment: here the upload with the test.html where i implemented for test purpouse your code with different pictures, still divs stay the same even i increase the like counter from picture 2 alot https://easyupload.io/1pmnaf

Comment: @TomersonJefferson That's strange. I've tested the test.html and the sort is working in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @TomersonJefferson I just found a fix and updated the code for the sort function in my answer. It's working now in Firefox, Chrome and IE and should also work in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will check it in a second. i was nearly at the finish line by myself i think but its just not working huehuehue :-*

Comment: Again thanks so much. just cant get it working in my existing script / files :) maybe another day when iam more wise i can figure it out

Comment: @TomersonJefferson Hope I was able to help you a bit and that you get it to work another day.

Comment: what i kiust dont get of your code in the javascript ist hte first line: $(document).on("click", ".textbox a", function() { // why is it the class ".textbox a" when there is no class with this name only .textbox ?

Comment: @TomersonJefferson The selector ".textbox a" selects the <a> tag that is inside the element with the class "textbox", so it selects the link one clicks to like a movie.

Comment: god damn iam stupid :) :) haha you so right. guess my brain melted today already. alltho iam very familiar with like css /sass selector schemes i fed up lol

Comment: if you still around maybe you are able to answer that aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427695/javascript-sort-isnt-working-for-arrays-of-more-than-10-objects-in-chrome

Comment: @TomersonJefferson I just answered your new question as comment as the question was closed. The values are strings and have to be parsed as integer using parseInt() (my mistake, I should have thought of that ;) )

Comment: hey. yes and stupid me who already learned about typeof and number and parseint didnt see thru it. // anyway since i added the parseint infront of it nothing works. haha. i mean the ordering isnt working. no errors, function gets called. still trying to debug :D

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :) - the problem was my live server wasnt working anymore in vcs haha. figured it out everything working iam happy thanks somuch

Comment: @TomersonJefferson Glad that I was able to help a bit and that you finally solved your problem :)

Comment: and the best thing is i completly udnerstand the logic behind the code since i google every little thing in it :) i hope i can help you aswell someday

Comment: Hey Matthias_h. if you still around here :) its like iam 2 minutes away from the solution and iam sitting since 4 hours ^^ -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472047/quick-sortfunction-array-by-specific-value/62472422#62472422

Comment: @TomersonJefferson I'm not sure if I can help you with that. Do you have a Fiddle your current code? It would be better to have your actual array instead of putting something together based on the image of that.

Comment: i have this codepen here: https://codepen.io/CodeLegend27/pen/ExPZRxa   is that what you meant ? its not working properly in the pen with the loop for inserting but it works for me :D - i just want to sort the array which i append to the html before i loop it by its dates. unfortunately i cant figure it out even tho with your previus code snippet i learned :)

Comment: @TomersonJefferson It's working here: https://codepen.io/matthias_h/pen/oNbBMWP I just used the sort function already given to you in the answer to your new question and only adjusted "date" to "dates" and the order to descending.

Comment: i gonna check it out in a bit have to put my little son to bed :) but WHAAT. only because i was missing an s . god damn 6 hours for nothing huehue. matthias you just a Code GOOD!!!

Comment: how can i thank you matthias_h?? maybe i can invite you to a dinner sometimes ? i live near vienna / austria :D